Saving files in MacOS
I develop an app in Python in MacOS. The app sometimes saves a file. The app has the writing permissions. When I run the code from the IDE, it works ok and saves the file. When I create an executable file (I use pyinstaller) and run it from the Terminal, it runs ok and saves the file. When I copy the executable to the Application folder, it runs ok, but fails to save the file.
In the Save popup I choose the folder, the file name, press Save button, the popup closes, but there is no saved file in the specified location.
How can I fix it?

'it fails' is not a good description of a problem. Describe the exact symptoms, with logs, debugging information, code, etc.

In the Save popup I choose the folder, the file name, press Save button, the popup closes, but there is no saved file in the specified location.

you did not include any code, there is no information at all of what you do, so we cannot really help you.

I asked ChatGPT the same question, it helped. Sorry for bothering you here...
